Как отправить DELETE запрос с body из TRESTRequest?
Понимаю, что TRESTRequest в принципе не рассчитан отправлять body в DELETE запросах. Но многие серверы сейчас их принимают. Может быть есть возможность как-то изящно обойти этот недочет компонента? Например как это можно сделать на TIdHTTP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53018006/how-to-send-indy-request-with-delete-methode-and-json-stream-source-in-delphi-7

Разобрался в вопросе, поэтому отвечу сам себе. Отправка body в DELETE запросах вTRESTRequest реализована в Delphi Embarcadero с версии 10.3 и выше. До версии 10.2 включительно, запросы GET и DELETE отправку bodyне поддерживают.
